# Angularjs strange behaviour of a modal directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items I want to edit using a modal window.
I built a directive to open a modal window when I click on the "edit" button of each item, passing the item itself to the modal ( with a "form-object" attribute ).

But I get this strange behaviour:

**{{formObject}}** always prints the **last item**, while **console.log(scope.formObject)** prints the **correct** one.

this is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/N5ta15yctYFgmQPqwXr4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `compile` function here. This works:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myAppModule.controller('TextController',
        function($scope) {          
            $scope.userModel = [{id:'1',name:'user1'},{id:'2',name:'user2'},{id:'3',name:'user3'}];
        });

    myAppModule.directive('formModal', ['$http', '$compile', function($http, $compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                formObject: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                var template, $element, loader;

                loader = $http.get('modal.html')
                        .success(function(data) {
                            template = data;                               
                        });

                loader.then(function() {
                    $element = angular.element($compile(template)(scope));
                });

                scope.close = function() {
                    $element.modal('hide');
                };

                element.on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $element.modal('show');
                });

            }
        }
    }]);
```